# Preventing tokens from containing a space in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, tokenize

Is there an option in [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)'s [tokenizer](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html) to prevent tokens from containing a space?

E.g. if the sentence is "my phone is 617 1555-6644", the substring "617 1555" should be Into two different tokens.

I am aware of the option [`normalizeSpace`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml):

> normalizeSpace: Whether any spaces in tokens (phone numbers, fractions get turned into U+00A0 (non-breaking space). It's dangerous to turn this off for most of our Stanford NLP software, which assumes no spaces in tokens.

but I don't want tokens to contain any space, including non-breaking space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the `tokenize.whitespace` option to true, but this will tokenize always and only on whitespace. For example, "it's" will not longer tokenize to "it  's".

Comment: Thanks, tokenizing only on spaces is a bit rough though :/