# Why do CoreNLP ner tagger and ner tagger join the separated numbers together?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, pycorenlp

Here is the code snippet:

```
In [390]: t
Out[390]: ['my', 'phone', 'number', 'is', '1111', '1111', '1111']

In [391]: ner_tagger.tag(t)
Out[391]: 
[('my', 'O'),
 ('phone', 'O'),
 ('number', 'O'),
 ('is', 'O'),
 ('1111\xa01111\xa01111', 'NUMBER')]
```

What I expect is:

```
Out[391]: 
[('my', 'O'),
 ('phone', 'O'),
 ('number', 'O'),
 ('is', 'O'),
 ('1111', 'NUMBER'),
 ('1111', 'NUMBER'),
 ('1111', 'NUMBER')]
```

As you can see the artificial phone number is joined by \xa0 which is said to be a non-breaking space. Can I separate that by setting the CoreNLP without changing other default rules.

The ner_tagger is defined as:

```
ner_tagger = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='ner')
```

Comment: Could you show the full Python code of how you called `CoreNLPParser`? Otherwise there's not enough information to figure why that's happening.

Comment: @alvas Yes. I have updated it.

Comment: Ah now this is interesting =)

Comment: Thanks for catching this! Issue raised on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

NLTK was reading the list of tokens into a string and before passing it to the CoreNLP server. And CoreNLP retokenize the inputs and concatenated the number-like tokens with `\xa0` (non-breaking space).

---

## In Long

Lets walk through the code, if we look at the `tag()` function from `CoreNLPParser`, we see that it calls the `tag_sents()` function and converted the input list of strings into a string before calling the `raw_tag_sents()` which allows `CoreNLPParser` to re-tokenized the input, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/corenlp.py#L348:

```
def tag_sents(self, sentences):
    """
    Tag multiple sentences.
    Takes multiple sentences as a list where each sentence is a list of
    tokens.

    :param sentences: Input sentences to tag
    :type sentences: list(list(str))
    :rtype: list(list(tuple(str, str))
    """
    # Converting list(list(str)) -> list(str)
    sentences = (' '.join(words) for words in sentences)
    return [sentences[0] for sentences in self.raw_tag_sents(sentences)]

def tag(self, sentence):
    """
    Tag a list of tokens.
    :rtype: list(tuple(str, str))
    >>> parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='ner')
    >>> tokens = 'Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split()
    >>> parser.tag(tokens)
    [('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'),
    ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'O')]
    >>> parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='pos')
    >>> tokens = "What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?".split()
    >>> parser.tag(tokens)
    [('What', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'),
    ('airspeed', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('an', 'DT'),
    ('unladen', 'JJ'), ('swallow', 'VB'), ('?', '.')]
    """
    return self.tag_sents([sentence])[0]
```

And when calling then the `raw_tag_sents()` passes the input to the server using the `api_call()`:

```
def raw_tag_sents(self, sentences):
    """
    Tag multiple sentences.
    Takes multiple sentences as a list where each sentence is a string.

    :param sentences: Input sentences to tag
    :type sentences: list(str)
    :rtype: list(list(list(tuple(str, str)))
    """
    default_properties = {'ssplit.isOneSentence': 'true',
                          'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,' }

    # Supports only 'pos' or 'ner' tags.
    assert self.tagtype in ['pos', 'ner']
    default_properties['annotators'] += self.tagtype
    for sentence in sentences:
        tagged_data = self.api_call(sentence, properties=default_properties)
        yield [[(token['word'], token[self.tagtype]) for token in tagged_sentence['tokens']]
                for tagged_sentence in tagged_data['sentences']]
```

**So the question is how to resolve the problem and get the tokens as it's passed in?**

If we look at the options for the Tokenizer in CoreNLP, we see the `tokenize.whitespace` option:

- https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html#options
- [Preventing tokens from containing a space in Stanford CoreNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440495/preventing-tokens-from-containing-a-space-in-stanford-corenlp)

If we make some changes to the allow additional `properties` before calling `api_call()`, we can enforce the tokens as it's passed to the CoreNLP server joined by whitespaces, e.g. changes to the code:

```
def tag_sents(self, sentences, properties=None):
    """
    Tag multiple sentences.

    Takes multiple sentences as a list where each sentence is a list of
    tokens.

    :param sentences: Input sentences to tag
    :type sentences: list(list(str))
    :rtype: list(list(tuple(str, str))
    """
    # Converting list(list(str)) -> list(str)
    sentences = (' '.join(words) for words in sentences)
    if properties == None:
        properties = {'tokenize.whitespace':'true'}
    return [sentences[0] for sentences in self.raw_tag_sents(sentences, properties)]

def tag(self, sentence, properties=None):
    """
    Tag a list of tokens.

    :rtype: list(tuple(str, str))

    >>> parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='ner')
    >>> tokens = 'Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split()
    >>> parser.tag(tokens)
    [('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'),
    ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'O')]

    >>> parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='pos')
    >>> tokens = "What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?".split()
    >>> parser.tag(tokens)
    [('What', 'WP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'),
    ('airspeed', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('an', 'DT'),
    ('unladen', 'JJ'), ('swallow', 'VB'), ('?', '.')]
    """
    return self.tag_sents([sentence], properties)[0]

def raw_tag_sents(self, sentences, properties=None):
    """
    Tag multiple sentences.

    Takes multiple sentences as a list where each sentence is a string.

    :param sentences: Input sentences to tag
    :type sentences: list(str)
    :rtype: list(list(list(tuple(str, str)))
    """
    default_properties = {'ssplit.isOneSentence': 'true',
                          'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,' }

    default_properties.update(properties or {})

    # Supports only 'pos' or 'ner' tags.
    assert self.tagtype in ['pos', 'ner']
    default_properties['annotators'] += self.tagtype
    for sentence in sentences:
        tagged_data = self.api_call(sentence, properties=default_properties)
        yield [[(token['word'], token[self.tagtype]) for token in tagged_sentence['tokens']]
                for tagged_sentence in tagged_data['sentences']]
```

After changing the above code:

```
>>> from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
>>> ner_tagger = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='ner')
>>> sent = ['my', 'phone', 'number', 'is', '1111', '1111', '1111']
>>> ner_tagger.tag(sent)
[('my', 'O'), ('phone', 'O'), ('number', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('1111', 'DATE'), ('1111', 'DATE'), ('1111', 'DATE')]
```